# Python not executing on time.mktime condition in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, time, conditional-statements, mktime

I have a small script I was going to use to execute a system command at a specified time ("commandTime") and then exit a specified time afterwards ("stopTime").  However, when I run the script it more often than not will never execute the command under the "if" statement.  (It will sometimes execute and sometimes won't.)

Assuming I'm not a total idiot (jury is still out on that...) and am setting the time variables reasonably, the script should execute the print command inside the if statement when 'time.mktime(time.localtime())' is equal to or greater than the formatted 'commandTime' variable.

---

Here is an excerpt of the code in  question:

```
import time

commandTime = time.strptime('2013-03-01 05:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
stopTime = time.strptime('2013-03-01 05:10:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


while (time.mktime(time.localtime()) <= time.mktime(stopTime)):
 if (time.mktime(time.localtime()) >= time.mktime(commandTime)):
  print "Green team go"
 time.sleep(100)
```

---

Assuming the stopTime and commandTime variables are set so the following is true when you execute the script:
time.localtime() < commandTime < stopTime

The script should loop through the while statement until time.localtime() is equal to or greater than stopTime, checking the if condition each loop.  Once time.localtime() is greater than  or equal to commandTime, the print command should execute.

I'm using time.mktime() to convert the datetime object into Unix time (a float I think) in order to make the comparison in both the while loop as well as the if statement.

The while loop works reliably each and every time, it's only the if statement that fails to execute most of the time.

I'm running python 2.7.3 on Debian Squeeze 32-bit.

My question is this:  What am I doing wrong in this script that is causing the if statement to not execute when the condition is met?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it set up currently is making the following true:
commandTime <= time.localtime()  <= stopTime

If you want it to be the way you have said you want it (localtime < commandtime < stoptime) you will have to do the following:

```
import time

commandTime = time.strptime('2013-03-05 21:40:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
stopTime = time.strptime('2013-03-05 21:50:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


while (time.mktime(time.localtime()) <= time.mktime(stopTime)):
  if (time.mktime(time.localtime()) <= time.mktime(commandTime)):
    print ("Green team go")
  time.sleep(100)
```

If you just misprinted the way you want it to execute, and you actually want commandTime <= time.localtime()  <= stopTime, I tried this way in python 3.2 on Windows (changed print to a function, with my local times inserted) and it works with commandTime and stopTime variables set properly, so it must be something to do with Python 2.7 or Debian Squeeze.

```
import time

commandTime = time.strptime('2013-03-05 21:40:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
stopTime = time.strptime('2013-03-05 21:50:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


while (time.mktime(time.localtime()) <= time.mktime(stopTime)):
  if (time.mktime(time.localtime()) >= time.mktime(commandTime)):
    print ("Green team go")
  time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: I have just tried this in 2.7.3 on Windows and it also worked (second code break I put). Also make sure you are setting the right dates for the commandtime (ie. 2013-05-03)

Comment: You're correct Nolan, the code I pasted is correct however I entered the comparison incorrectly.  You're comparison is correct: commandTime <= time.localtime() <= stopTime.

Answer (score 0):

The code posted in general appears ok.  Note that calling `time.localtime()` will return different results for the `while` and `if` loops.  If in your real code you have some long-running task between the `i`f and `while`, and start/stop times are close together, then you may well have the case where the `while` drops through, but before the `if` executes time has moved on far enough for the test to fail.

You could rewrite to something like the following.  This caches the current time for comparison purposes (`nowSec`), and avoids costly time conversions on each loop.

```
import time

commandTime = time.strptime('2013-03-01 05:00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
stopTime = time.strptime('2013-03-01 05:10:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

commandTimeSec = time.mktime(commandTime)
stopTimeSec = time.mktime(stopTime)

while True:
    nowSec = time.mktime(time.localtime())

    if nowSec > stopTimeSec:
        break

    if nowSec >= commandTimeSec:
        print "Green team go"
    time.sleep(100)
```

Comment: Thanks Austin, there isn't a whole lot going on between the if and the while but I'll definitely test your suggested format in the morning to see if it behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code was fine, the problem was associated with the length of time specified in the sleep statement combined with how close together (in time) the command and stop variables were.

If I set sleep to 100 seconds but then set the time difference between command and stop to less than 100 seconds, it was possible to not trigger the command on an iteration (because it wasn't time yet), wait 100 seconds ("sleeping" through the command time), and then immediately exiting the loop because we had hit or exceeded our stop variable.

Thanks for the help!!

NOTE: If I had a high enough reputation, I would +1 Austin's answer since it was his cleaner loop logic I used to dial-in on the actual issue.